# Set solution wide namepsace in VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, namespaces

is it possible to specify the same default root namespace for all projects within a solution in Visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

(I suspect that you asked the wrong question. If so, please correct your question.)

Comment: I added 'default' to the question. Can you explain how my question is 'wrong'?

Comment: I don't know what the correct question is, therefore I can't explain what is wrong with your question. As for your modified question, I'm not sure what you mean by "default". If you mean "default root namespace for newly created projects", then it's likely that the correct question is "Is it possible to specify a default namespace for new VS projects?".

Comment: I already know how to specify a default namespace for a new VS project, I want to know if I can do the same for the entire solution.

Comment: Only projects have a namespace -- and they only have one, so it doesn't make sense to refer to it as a "default" namespace when there is no such thing as a non-default namespace. Solutions don't have a namespace, nor a default namespace. Did you mean to ask how to *change* the namespace of all solution projects to the same value?

Comment: No, I just meant if you in some way set the default namespace for each project in a solution at the solution level rather than each project individually. Thanks for your input.